# MySQLi Insert into inserts 0?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form on my website that submits data to my (mysql) database. This is done via Mysqli. After submission of the form I get the message:

> "inputoftextboxhere" has been added to the database!.

But when I look in my database there is only a value of 0.

**insert.php**

```
<?php
//config bestand ophalen. 
require_once 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO maillist (id, email) VALUES ('', '$email')";

if ($mysqli->query($sql))
{
    echo "<center><div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>".$email." is succesvol toegevoegd aan de database!</div></center>";
} 
else 
{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
}
    $mysqli->close();
}

?>
```

Index.php

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form" name="submit">   
            <legend>Email </legend>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="E-mail"  /><br />                   
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block signup-btn" name="submit" type="submit">Voeg nummer toe</button>
        </form>
```

Screenshot of database:
https://gyazo.com/9ec48d3ce4ec6643d8fbcb2f3db42052

Comment: only a few lines of database details. Don't think you need them. ;)

Comment: Also the table definition and check for triggers.Sometimes people connect with mysql that`s why I asked.

Comment: I didn't. Only made the connection there.

Comment: Why this database definition typo question has been so much upvoted?

Comment: Your success message exposes your site to XSS attacks. When printing user-provided data within the context of a web page, you always need to escape it. [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is often sufficient.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Guess it was updated by alternate accounts of that user or he sent the link someone and told him to upvote it.

Comment: Check Datatype of email column, set it to varchar or text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the database can store strings, so pick **Varchar**.
When it is set too **boolean/bit** or any number-based datatype your database doesnt now how to handle a string input.
Otherwise, debug the value that is getting posted to make sure you aren't just putting a zero in your database.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the datatype of the email column in your database table is **text** or **varchar**. If it is set to **integer** or **double** probably that might be the issue.